How can I determine, using Powershell, without MS Graph, the ability of a user to use Self Service Password Reset (SSPR)?
I don't have access to Microsoft Graph in my environment due to permissions afforded me.
MSOnline, in addition to being deprecated, only allows pulling 30 days of records.
Is there any other way to, regardless of how long ago SSPR was setup, determine the ability of a user to use SSPR, for a Powershell script to advise on options for password resets?

Have the staff with access to the M365/Entra ID system to use graph or get those stats, and automate daily, weekly, etc. dump for you to use with Import-Csv in some path to you have access to query that exported data. If you do not have access to get the data you need from the system and methods they allow, then ask someone in your environment that does, or for advice how to get this data for your reporting needs. You just need the data, not necessarily access to query if from the system, let them do that, then you get the data from that location. Executives got your back too?

They can technically register an M365 app and define the properties to use token graph authentication with proper scopes, schedule, and automate the data extraction for you. There are secure ways using Graph and PowerShell to get what you need. If you need the data, have the security staff help you with available options and configurations to get it somewhere for you. If it's a lost cause and no one else but you thinks it is important & you do not have access, then live without it or persuade otherwise in your system to manipulate accordingly. Get in their ears & have others w/ power advocate.

Consider transitioning from the deprecated MSOnline module to the AzureAD or MSGraph module for managing SSPR settings. AzureAD provides more robust capabilities and support for modern environments. Ensure your scripts are updated to utilize these modules to effectively determine and manage SSPR status across your organization.

Sorry, can AzureAD alone (can't use MS Graph due to permissions) obtain status of SSPR setup?
